# Need to prove that "If $x+y \ge 1$ then $x \ge \frac 12$ or $y \ge \frac 12$"

Tags: inequality

So I have this one homework assignment where I have to prove the following clause "If $x+y \ge 1$ then $x \ge \frac 12$ or $y \ge \frac 12$". I thought that if I assign $x=y$ and put it like "$2x \ge 1$" and solve the x, does it actually prove that either of them(or both) need to be greater than 1/2?

The clause "If $x + y ≥ 1$ then $x ≥ 1/2$ or $y ≥ 1/2$"

Edit x,y are real numbers

Sorry if this is too simple to post here or something but I've always had problems with the proving assignments which I really need to start learning as I started in university like two weeks ago. I am not asking for complete solution, tips are ok.

Comment: If $x,y<\frac12, x+y<1$

Comment: I agree with @labbhattacharjee. Argue by contraposition.

Comment: Without loss of generality, suppose that $x \geqslant y$. Then $2x \geqslant x + y \dotsc$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, a more logical statement is at least one of $x,y$ is $\ge\frac12$ if $x+y\ge1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Isn't the negation of the If "x + y ≥ 1" then x ≥ 1/2 or y ≥ 1/2" clause "There are real numbers x and y, x ≥ 1/2 or y ≥ 1/2 if x+y < 1 ? Or did I get it completely wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that it’s not true, i.e., that $x<\frac12$ and $y<\frac12$; what can you then say about $x+y$?

Comment: Then x + y ≥ 1 can't be true so the negation is wrong which makes the original statement true, but I don't really get how I should write it on the paper the part where I show that x + y ≥ 1 is false? Do I assign the x=y and show it that way?

Comment: @Samuli: You could say something like this: If $x<\frac12$ and $y<\frac12$, then $x+y<\frac12+\frac12=1$, contradicting the hypothesis that $x+y\ge 1$. Therefore it’s not the case that both $x$ and $y$ are less than $\frac12$, so either $x\ge\frac12$ or $y\ge\frac12$ (or both). (You don’t actually need proof by contradiction here: this can also be phrased as a [proof of the *contrapositive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive). The contrapositive of a statement *p implies q* is *not-p implies not-q*; the two are logically equivalent, so proving one proves the other.)

Comment: Yeah. We haven't dealt with the proof of the contrapositive yet in class so I thought the teacher would assume that we'd use the contradiction method but I guess it's fine to use the contrapositive too. Is it correct too if I do it with the contradiction method like I said?

Comment: @Samuli: Yes, it is. (I thought that contradiction might be more familiar; that’s why I wrote it up that way.)

Comment: Ok, great! I understand now, thanks!

Comment: @Samuli: Your’e welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You have $\max(x,y)+\min(x,y) \ge 1$. Since $\max(x,y)\ge\min(x,y)$, this becomes
$2 \max(x,y) \ge 1$, or in other words,
$$ \max(x,y) \ge \frac{1}{2}$$